# Can see website functions and run them from console?

Tags: javascript, security, developer-console

Javascript question here. Should one be able to see a script tag in the body of the developer console and then run those functions directly on the website? It seems like this is a security issue and there should be a way to prevent this displaying in the browser via some kind of encryption or security method that would make your JavaScript functions unreadable.

Thanks,

Comment: The user agent (browser) needs to be able to execute code. If there is secret code (or secret variables) then those can't be supplied to the client.

Comment: "*Should one be able to see a script tag in the body of the developer console and then run those functions directly on the website?*" yes. "*It seems like this is a security issue*" you're not supposed to put things that will compromise the security of your app in your front-end code. "*there should be a way to prevent this displaying in the browser*" JavaScript source code is just text. As is HTML. That's how the internet works - with publicly available source code we reach with ordinary HTTP calls. If *the browser* hides the information, anybody can just download the file. It's not a secret.

Comment: Code that should be protected from the user tampering must be on the server, not the client.

Comment: The clue is in the "Script" part of JavaScript...

Comment: @JoshWulf there is also the "Java" part of JavaScript but it's not really related. Names can be deceiving.

Comment: @VLAZ - true story!

Answer (score 1):

While there's technically no way to do this and you should always assume that anything on the front end is not secure, you can use scoping to accomplish some of what you're after, an example would be:

```
const Sample = (() => {
    function Sample() { 
        const hiddenFunc1 = (() => { });
        const hiddenFunc2 = (() => { });
        
        hiddenFunc1();
        hiddenFunc2();
    }

    Sample.prototype.visibleFunc1 = function(){ }
    Sample.prototype.visibleFunc2 = function(){ }

    return Sample;
})();
```

Now when in a separate file you will only ever have `Sample.visibleFunc1` & `Sample.visibleFunc2` accessible, `hiddenFunc1` & `hiddenFunc2` are limited to the constructors scope and are essentially private functions.

Note that in order to use the design pattern above you would need to initialize it as such:

```
const sample = new Sample();
sample.visibleFunc1();
sample.visibleFunc2();
```

Comment: As a user, I can put a breakpoint inside the IIFE, export the private functions to global ones `window.totallyNotHiddenFunc1 = hiddenFunc1` and have complete freedom how and when I run them manually. Or I can re-write the source code before it's executed by the browser. So, this doesn't achieve security. Hiding functions is useful for organising your code, though.

Comment: Agreed this doesnt achieve any level of security. But if you're designing an sdk and have certain functions that you dont want exposed to the end developer this is one approach. As with most things in the browser with enough ingenuity any developer could find their way around the file, download it, modify it and do as they please.

Comment: As I said - useful for code organisation. But OP seems to be concerned that users have direct access to anything that runs in the browser. Which they do.

Comment: Very true, its good to assume that nothing on the front end is secure.

Comment: This answers my question/assumptions. I figured this was the case, but in short this would also be a reason why you have to guard heavily against cross scripting attacks. Since standard functionality permits function visibility, an XSS attack has just as much access to the functions as the user does. So the security principle would be to guard against xss attacks, not so much hiding your functions?

Comment: @thinker XSS is not caused by the user being able to see and tamper with code. It's caused by code not correctly handling other code. In a lot of cases because of actually handling somethin *as code* when it doesn't need to be. `$("#something").html(value)` is a simple way to show some text on the screen but it actually directly puts that as HTML code. So, for `value = "<script>alert('xss')</script>"` you're vulnerable. Handling that as *non-code* will prevent problems: `$("#something").text(value)` will not try to interpret anything.

Comment: But if the code was vulnerable to xss, all other functions in the code would be accessible via the injected script, correct? My comments are more saying where to focus your security efforts. Making the code hidden as the solution suggests, doesn't really provide a security option, but protecting against xss is a better use of time.

Comment: "*if the code was vulnerable to xss, all other functions in the code would be accessible via the injected script, correct?*" yes. All code that runs on the client-side can do anything all other code that runs on the client-side can do. This is what XSS leverages - trying to slip some code that gets run. Once it's running on the client-side, it can do anything. Including tamper with other "hidden" functions or circumventing them. Perhaps even re-writing the whole HTML or logging all of the user's keystrokes, etc. Preventing XSS from happening is priority, protecting from realised XSS is doomed.